# How to set StringArray value on click on array item in android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-spinner

I'm working with an android spinner. Here I have two arrays in my XML like below and I'm showing **car** array in mine spinner.

```
<string-array name="car">
    <item>128i Coupe</item>
    <item>M3 Coupe</item>
    <item>M5 Sedan</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="value">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

Now I can call the any of them in my Java file like this

```
String[] BMW_Model = MainActivity.this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.car);
```

I can get/print the value of this item on click by this way

```
String td = spinnerManufacture.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Now what I need is when I click on an item of my **car** array I should display the value of my second **value** array according to the position. As an example.

> If I click on **M5 Sedan** from my spinner item it should show **2** in a Toast message from my second array.

Any kind of suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have completely different arrays, the solution to your problem could be to get the position of the pressed spinner element and get the value of the second array at this index.

```
int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()

String[] valueArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.value);

Toast.makeText(context,  valueArray[position],Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If you need to display toast on click, then you need to set clickListener

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really missed that part. The perfect solution for me.